# Project task schedule with cronjobs in NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have projects with Automatic Report settings. The user has an interface on the project and he can set on each project for ex.

DAILY (every day or at every X days)

WEEKLY (he can select the week days and also can be able to say "i need this at every 2,3,4 etc weeks)

MONTHLY (he can select the days and to check if he want to have it at the end of every month)

In database for each project i'm inserting in a table CronJobs a collection like this:

```
  id: string;

  name: string; // name of the job (ProjectReport)

  entityType: string; // name of the entity (in my case Project)

  entityId: string; // id of the entity (of the Project)

  frequency: //(daily, weekly, monthly, never) ;

  every: number; // (every x days/ weeks/ months)

  on: number[]; // (for weekly/ monthly I need to know in which days I will execute the job)

  timezone: string;

  startDate: Date;
  
  endDate: Date;

  lastRunDate: Date;
```

For now I created a cron that will run hourly. I don't know exactly the best way to decide if I need to run or not the cronjob. If someone can help me with some ideas?

For example the user is setting that he want to have a report weekly on Monday and Friday starting from 2020-05-12 12:20 every 1 week.

I need to consider that the server can die so to prevent sending the report twice on some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you are looking for [agenda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda).
Since you are already using a mongodb to store your scheduled jobs, this won't really create much more overhang.

Agenda can handle cron string as you are using now, it will handle if the server has downtime, and catch up with any missed jobs/ensure jobs are only executed once.

Comment: Hello @Enslev I saw something about agenda, but I don't understand how is able to handle all changes dynamically considering that each project has different settings

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: How is agenda able to generate the reports dinamically without doing manual handles? And how can I create a relation between Project and Cron? Because after the cron is created the user need to be able to see the settings of the cron for specific project and also to be able to update the settings.

Comment: basically for 3 projects for example I will have 3 agendaCrons and each will need to send a report based on some settings. How can I change/ cancel a cron for project X?